# Counting number of occurrences [R]

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                 type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','sofa'),
                 num=c(4,5,12,4,6))
```

For each row, I want to count the number of times that "type" appears with a num value >4, and then create a new column. So for the first row, "chair" appears once with a value of 5, so it gets assigned a 1. For the second row, same thing. For the 3rd row, sofa appears twice with a value >4. So all unique "types" will end up having the same value:

```
df
#    name  type num count
# 1 black chair   4     1
# 2 black chair   5     1
# 3 black  sofa  12     2
# 4   red  sofa   4     2
# 5   red  sofa   6     2
```

Comment: Did you meant `df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(count = sum(num>4))` or with `base R` `with(df, ave(num > 4, type, FUN = sum))`

Answer (score 1):

```
df$count = ave(df$num, df$type, FUN = function(x) sum(x>4))
df$count
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   mutate(count = sum(num>4))
```

---

Or with `base R` (as we commented earlier)

```
df$count <- with(df, ave(num > 4, type, FUN = sum))
```